# razor class validations on entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

Quick question on best practices.

I have one project MVC3 + razor that on my class, on each of my properties, I have some validations like these:

```
    [StringLength(20)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[1-9][0-9]*$",ErrorMessage="Only Numbers Allowed") ]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please Inform The Code")]
    [Display(Name = "Code")]
    public string gCode { get; set; }
```

This is on my, let's say, Customer class on my model. Validation works perfectly on the UI.

On a second project, when using Entity Framework - database first, I have my edmx file with my entities and I query the database using ObjectContext, which means the Customer class is built by EF.

Where am I supposed to add these validations now?

Comment: I am...but I dont have all my properties redeclared on my viewModel. Maybe Im not using the correct way. can you give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model first has this problem - but it can be solved using MetaData.  Say you have a generated entity called `Field` and the Value field you want to decorate with a `[Required]` attribute, just do the following:

```
namespace Model.Entities {

    [MetadataType(typeof(FieldMetadata))]
    public partial class Field : EntityBase {

    }

    class FieldMetadata {
        [Required]
        public object Value;
    }
}
```

Here you are adding metadata to the Value member of an existing class's members that you cannot modify.

EDIT: If it doesn't work, make a call to the TypeDescriptor as well.

```
TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(Field), typeof(FieldMetadata)), typeof(Field));
```

Comment: thanks Quinton! Not sure if I get you. The Fields clas s is already declared on my Model.Designer.cs how am I supposed to redelcare it?

Comment: It's a partial class, so you can re-declare it.

Comment: chan I do it on a different cs file? Because I dont think I should change the one EF generated

Comment: You must create a separate class file.  It's the only way to do it.

Comment: I did. It works, but this approach makes necessary to edit the class generated by EF, whihc is not good because the changes would be overwritten if the class is re-generated..

Comment: You do not have to edit the existing class file.  The entity generated by EF is a partial class so create a separate class file and redefine the entity as in my sample code